# IntellijIdea Mongo connection too slow and lack of capabilities

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea, datagrip

I'm trying to use IntellijIdea in order to connect to MongoDB but it seems to work too slow. A simple read request might take up to 5 secs meanwhile Robo 3T works almost instantly. Is it a common and known behavior (some issue with mongo driver for example) or is it my local issue?

Also I can't find how to manage collections\databases via GUI. Let's say I want to create a new database: I right-click in order to get a context menu, go to "new" section and everything I can do is to add a new datasource, driver or just jump to console.
Also I can't find db users for the given database. There is just no such folder under selected db.
Can I do such kind of management via IntellijIdea database GUI?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately we found a problem with latest MongoDB driver, which causes slow operations. Please open up data source properties, switch to Drivers tab, select MongoDB and switch to v.1.11.
And I've created 2 feature request based on your feedback, please follow and vote to get noticed on any updates:

- For database management GUI https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-14252
- For user list https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-14253

Comment: Driver switching solved the issue. Thanks.
Pretty surprised that such kind of basic managament is not out of the box in such tool as Intellij\Datagrip. But thanks for creating feature requests on that.

Comment: Wow! Connection time from 20s to 3s, thanks! Thanks, helped me a lot!